# fluentd convert field to integer

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, type-conversion, fluentd

I need your help.
I have `fluentd` configured in tail mode to send my logs to a `elasticsearch` cluster.
I'm using a `regex` to parse each log line but for some fields I need to convert `metricValue` in `integer`. I've tried some things but is not working.

Here is my fluentd conf file:

```
    <source>
    @type tail
    path /tmp/application.log
    pos_file /tmp/access.log.pos
    format multi_format
    tag first.log

    <pattern>
      format /(?<app>.*)\((?<instance>.*)\) CID\((?<correlationId>.*)\) (?<level>.*) \[(?<timestamp>.*)\] \[(?<Thread>.*)\] (?<class>.*) - \[Provider:(?<providerName>.*),Curef:(?<cuRef>.*),Operation:(?<operation>.*),Reference:(?<reference>.*),Idx:(?<idx>.*)\]/
    </pattern>
    <pattern>
      format /(?<app>.*)\((?<instance>.*)\) CID\((?<correlationId>.*)\) (?<level>.*) \[(?<timestamp>.*)\] \[(?<Thread>.*)\] (?<class>.*) - (?<body>.*)/
    </pattern>
  </source>
  <match *.log>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type stdout
    </store>
    <store>
      @type elasticsearch
      host localhost
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix fluentd-log
      flush_interval 10s
    </store>
  </match>
```

I found in the fluend documentation the syntax but is not working (and I don't know where to put these line)

```
types <field_name_1>:<type_name_1>,<field_name_2>:<type_name_2>,...
```

I want to convert the field metricValue to integer before sending it to `elasticsearch`.

Thanks for any idea.

C.C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put these fields (`types <field_name_1>:<type_name_1>,<field_name_2>:<type_name_2>,...`) into the `source` section in your case.
And if you use [parser](https://github.com/tagomoris/fluent-plugin-parser) plugin, you have to insert it inside the `filter` section (here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39742322/parse-nginx-ingress-logs-in-fluentd))